# Jquery: how to make div disappear when click outside

Tags: jquery

I tried Chinnu R's approach, but when I click anywhere outside the div, menu items not hiding, only when I click inside the div, menu items hide, I want the opposite, ie, click outside div, hide, click inside div, stay put.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $('div#nomore').toggle();
        });


        $("body > *").not("body > button").click(function(e) {
            $('div#nomore').hide();
        });
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<button>MENU</button>
<div id="nomore" style="display:none; background-color:yellow; width:300px;">
<br>
<a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a><br>
ITEM 2<br>
ITEM 3<br>
ITEM 4<br>
ITEM 5<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this jsfiddle,i think rhis will solve your problem. 


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/jc7xA/1/

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this,

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                $('div#nomore').toggle();
            });

            $("body").click(function(e) {
                 if(e.target.id == "nomore"){
                     $('div#nomore').hide();
                 }
            });
        });
```

Other method:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                $('div#nomore').toggle();
            });         


            $("body > *").not("body > button").click(function(e) {
                $('div#nomore').hide();
            });
        });
```

Updated code:

```
            $("body > *").not("body > button").click(function(e) {
                 console.log(e.target.id);
                if(e.target.id=='nomore'){
                        return false;
                 }
                 $('div#nomore').hide();

            });
```

Comment: Chinnu, I tried the second method, it's so close but not quite, because when I click on the div, menu items hide alright, but I want menu items to hide when click *outside* the div.

Comment: how do I modify to exclude div for this statement:$("body > *").not("body > button").click(function(e) {

Comment: Updated the code can you check it

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('div#nomore').toggle();
});
$('body').click(function () {
    $('div#nomore').hide();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4TNJe/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
        $('div#nomore').hide();
});
```

Comment: will not show even when button is clicked!!!

Comment: try to fiddle it it will show when button is clicked!!

Answer (score 1):

`stopPropagation` on the events for `button` and `div#nomore` and bind a click to `window`.

That way when `window` is click anywhere but `button` or `div#nomore`, it will hide the menu.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(e){
        $('div#nomore').show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('div#nomore').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(window).click(function(){
        $('div#nomore').hide();
    });
});
```

And if you want the menu to disappear when you click on one of the menu items, remove the `$('div#nomore').click ...` block.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/UxU6P/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('*:not(div#nomore)').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(e.currentTarget!='button' &&  $('div#nomore').is(':visible'))
    {
        $('div#nomore').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('div#nomore').toggle();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/aKEjUMO/1/)

Answer (score 1):

replace the div as shown below`

```
<div id="nomore" tabindex="-1" onblur="$('div#nomore').toggle();"
```

Answer (score 1):

after extensive research, I have determined that it is impossible to make this work on all platforms: desktop, android and iphones, need to adopt a different approach...

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("#yourDiv Id");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the div...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the div
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: no mouse, this is for mobile devices too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body :not(div#nomore)').on('click',function(){
 $('div#nomore').hide();
})
```

Comment: will not show even when button is clicked!!!